# Swft 3 Protocol Declaring Array with elements of Type with @objc

Tags: objective-c, swift3, swift-protocols

I have hard times with some protocol stuff in swift 3. My problem is that when I have this protocol:

```
@objc
protocol HHMapViewProtocol: class {
    init()
    func moveCamera(_ target: CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoom: Float, animated: Bool) -> Void
    func moveCamera(_ target: CLLocationCoordinate2D, animated: Bool) -> Void
    func positionCamera(on target: CLLocationCoordinate2D, facing at: CLLocationCoordinate2D, inDuration duration: CFTimeInterval)
    func setWaypoints(_ waypoints: [CLLocationCoordinate2D])
}
```

The last method in this protocol is generating error because:

```
Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because the type of
the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

What I don't understand is why the problem is only in Array. If I type:

```
func setWaypoints(_ waypoints: [NSObject])
```

Then everything is ok. Why CLLocationCoordinate2D in other functions is not a problem and in array case is a problem? Can somebody give some nice solution from API point of view because I want that this array should be parametrized. I know that CLLocationCoordinate2D is a struct and this cannot be represented in Objective-C but compiler doesn't complain with moveCamera functions and positionCamera.

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a (Objective-)C-struct and can surely represented in (Objective-)C. It is defined using that language.

`NSArray`, the class used for representing object arrays in Objective-C, cannot contain structs. One would use a C array in Objective-C, but Swift tries to use an instance of `NSArray` and recognize that this does not work.

Define a oop wrapper for `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, use `NSValue`, or crete a type that can contain a C array. The Swift compiler will understand that.